EC2::LaunchTemplate's Version, versus GetAtt, versus ImportValue
Stuff That Works
Background:  So AWS EC2 has this "just useful enough to put up with all the idiosyncracies" feature called Launch Templates, which implements its own revision control.  Any given revision of a template can be flagged as "the default version".
More background:  Using CloudFormation templates to deploy EC2 instances, it's possible to refer to an existing Launch Template like:
Resources:
  NewInstanceLogicalID:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: lt-12345abcde
        Version: 5

The AWS documentation for the Version notes that it is not optional, and that CFN has no simple value syntax for "the latest/default version".  Instead, if you don't want to hardcode the version or have the user enter it via a Parameters field, you can use Fn::GetAtt to retrieve the LatestVersionNumber/DefaultVersionNumber attribute of a template resource:
Resources:
  NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: 'some-descriptive-name-for-later-use'
      VersionDescription: 'In real life, this text is lyrical poetry.'
      LaunchTemplateData: .....

  NewInstanceLogicalID:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID
        Version: !GetAtt NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID.DefaultVersionNumber

Problem and Attempted Solutions
Direct !Ref/!GetAtt references to NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID only work if the CFT is creating a launch template in the same stack with every EC2 instance, which neatly defeats like ninety percent of the purpose of a launch template.  We want to be able to create launch templates, and then reuse them in later stacks.
Functions like Fn::GetAtt cannot accept existing AWS resource identifiers in the "logical ID" argument, so shenanigans like this wouldn't work by definition:
# These are defined to not work
Version: Fn::GetAtt: [ 'lt-12345abcde', 'DefaultVersionNumber' ]
Version: Fn::GetAtt: [ 'some-descriptive-name-for-later-use', 'DefaultVersionNumber' ]

But if one CFT stack creates and exports a launch template...
Resources:
  NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: 'some-descriptive-name-for-later-use'
      VersionDescription: 'In real life, this text is lyrical poetry.'
      LaunchTemplateData: .....

Outputs:
  LaunchTemplateOutput:
    Description: 'Again, such great description, much documentation.'
    Value: !Ref NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID
    Export:
      Name: 'ExportedLaunchTemplate'

...then subsequent CFTs can use !ImportValue to point to them:
Resources:
  NewInstanceLogicalID:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !ImportValue ExportedLaunchTemplate
        Version: this is where i lose my mind, patience, and hope

The LaunchTemplateId line as shown works.  The Version line is driving me bugnut crazy.  What I want is the moral equivalent of
Version: Fn::GetAtt: [ !ImportValue ExportedLaunchTemplate, 'DefaultVersionNumber' ]

but the GetAtt first argument can't use a function call like that.  You can enable language extensions to get some functions allowed in the logical ID argument, but they still don't include ImportValue in the list.  This makes sense, since exported values are just strings, not full "resource objects".
I know it's possible to have the first CFT add additional Outputs entries for more attributes of other CFN types, so we could probably do something similar to (untested):
Outputs:
  [LaunchTemplateOutput as before]

  LaunchTemplateVersionOutput:
    Value: !GetAtt NewLaunchTemplateLogicalID.DefaultVersionNumber
    Export:
      Name: 'ExportedLaunchTemplateVersion'

and then !ImportValue would work on that exported identifier.  But at best that would still only retrieve the default version at the time the exporting stack was deployed, i.e., 1, not the potentially different default version when the actual use case stack(s) were deployed later.
Is there a solution to this Version mess that can be done within CFN?  I realize the actual long-term solution is "CFN is one of the red-headed stepchildren at AWS, it gets as little development effort as possible, migrate all your stuff to Teraform or something else" but was hoping for something in the meantime.
